# Why I am getting error in dataloader in defining a NN?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to write a NN. However I am getting error.
Here is my Code:

```
tfms= transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),  #scale data to [0,1]
    transforms.Lambda(lambda t: (t*2)-1) #scale data to [-1,1]
])

datas= datasets.ImageFolder(root='D:\\Ali\\python files\\mycats\\', transform= tfms)
```

Then, when defining dataloader as

```
dataloader= torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datas, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, drop_last= True)
```

writing `image= next(iter(dataloader))[0]`,
I get error:

```
TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>.
```

What is wrong here and what should I do?

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback. It seems like in your `transforms.Compose()`, you are applying `transforms.ToTensor()` twice which might cause the issue. Remove the first `transforms.ToTensor()` and keep it as the last argument in `transforms.Compose()`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. That was the problem. Such a childish mistake I made :/

Comment: No worries, happy coding!